# Jquery datepicker load and open correctly but not change date value

Tags: razor, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am developing a web based application with MVC razor and i'm using Jquery datepicker a couple date field now datepicker load and open correctly but not change date value.i'm calling a partial view for edit using by jquery dialog.Actually if i make edit operation inside page(using query dialog use without partial view), everything is normally.

**EditDate.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0"
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditDate", "Home"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })
    <button>Update</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you load this partial view with AJAX chances are that the `$(function() { ... })` that you put inside won't be invoked and thus not attaching the plugin to the input field.

I would start by moving this javascript where it belongs: to a separate javascript file and not inside HTML views. I would also put this inside a named function:

```
function applyDatePickers() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0"
    });
}


$(function () {
    applyDatePickers(); // This is only for the initial DOM when the page is loaded
});
```

and then once you load the jQuery dialog from the server call the `applyDatePickers` function again. If you are using AJAX to load this partial, that would probably be inside the `success` callback of your AJAX request.

Comment: Darin, i has tried as you say, i seperated function and i put it on main page but problem still continue.